# This is the error I get after making the following code: TypeError: unorderable types: str() > method()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
SecretNumber=(random.randint)

Guess=input("Please enter your guess: ")
NumberofGuesses=1

while Guess != SecretNumber:
            NumberofGuesses=NumberofGuesses+1


            if Guess>SecretNumber:
               print("Please insert a smaller number")

            else:
               print("Please insert a bigger number")

print("Number of Guesses: {0}".format(NumberofGuesses))
```

Comment: You may want to read this:[Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import *
secretnumber = randint(0,10)
numberofGuesses += 1
guess = int(input())
```

just a few things to clean up the code, and fix the str problem
also, put the guessing part in the while loop

Comment: from random import*
SecretNumber=randint
Guess=int(input("Please enter Guess: "))

NumberofGuesses=1
SecretNumber=0


   
        
while Guess != SecretNumber:
            NumberofGuesses=NumberofGuesses+1

      
            if Guess>SecretNumber:
               print("Please insert a smaller number")

            else:
               print("Please insert a bigger number")

if Guess==SecretNumber:
   print("Number of Guesses: {0}".format(NumberofGuesses))


     

    
                                       




 
I did those things but now the program is not stopping.I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

1. You never convert the user's guess into an integer. That takes care of the `str` part. Use `Guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))`.
2. You never actually call the `random.randint` function, with `random.randint()`. That means `SecretNumber` is a function, not an integer, which takes care of the `method` part. Use `SecretNumber = random.randint(1, 10)` (for a random number between 1 and 10, inclusive).
3. You never have another prompt for input. Either add another `Guess =...` at the end of the loop, or move the one you already have to the beginning of the loop and use a `while True:` with a `break` on a matching number (in an `else` branch for the `if` structure you already have - the current `else` should be an `elif`; see below).
4. If the guess is too big, you state as much. However, you say the guess is too small in every other case, even though the guess might actually match. Replace that `else` with `elif Guess < SecretNumber`.